# React - Link with bearer token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to buy a link to download a file. But this request needs a bearer token, to be able to access the file. So I built this:

```
import { getUrl } from 'config/config';
import { useAuth } from 'oidc-react';
import { createRef } from 'react';

const AuthLink = ({ attachment, children }) => {
  const link = createRef();

  const { userData } = useAuth();

  const handleAction = async e => {
    const fullUrl = getUrl(attachment.path);

    if (link.current.href) return;

    const result = await fetch(fullUrl, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userData?.access_token}`,
      },
    });

    const blob = await result.blob();
    const href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    link.current.download = attachment.name;
    link.current.href = href;
    link.current.click();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <a role="button" ref={link} onClick={handleAction}>
        {children}
      </a>
    </>
  );
};

export default AuthLink;
```

This works fine, but I get a very annoying warning on the console, that I want to get rid of.

> Line 31:7:  The href attribute is required for an anchor to be keyboard accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide an href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md  jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid

What could I do, to make the error go away? Any try to add an "href" to the markup, has only messed with the logic, and blocked me from downloading the file.

Comment: Your link is stateful, are you're storing that state in the attributes of the anchor and inspecting it in your click handler. Why not use React's ways of handling state; have a component that has state, and renders a sub-component that is either the unauthed link or the authed link?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is that you are using an `<a>` element to perform double duty, where sometimes it is used as a link and sometimes as a button.

Use a real `<button>` instead of a link to trigger the click handler.

Then change the click handler so it generates a new link as a child of the body element, clicks it, then removes it once the download has started.

Comment: Is this what you meant? https://pastebin.com/raw/exLJqNLi